# push failed error message github large files

Tags: github

I am trying to install google maps and a few different framework on GitHub.
I am currently using the mac desktop, and I am not understand what I am doing wrong.

Github Mac file error:

```
File Pods/CardIO/CardIO/libCardIO.a is 96.28 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB        
File Pods/CardIO/CardIO/libopencv_core.a is 83.71 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB        
File Pods/CardIO/CardIO/libopencv_imgproc.a is 96.08 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB        
File Pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a is 52.72 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB        
GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.        
Trace: c683784b6d6c9afc2ef456aabef1b3bf        
See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.        
File Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/Versions/A/GoogleMaps is 123.05 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

My current `.gitattributes` file:

```
*.jpg filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text    
*.framework filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

Comment: ever figure this out?

Comment: @chicobermuda please check the answer below upvote the answer if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow this it will fix the issue
https://medium.com/@AyunasCode/how-to-push-large-files-to-github-253d05cc6a09#.kfvv2fu5z

Answer (score 4):

Note that since [Git LFS 2.2.0 (June 2017)](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/releases/tag/v2.2.0), the preferred way to import large file is with [`git lfs migrate import --include "*.a"`](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/d65f80119281b1b7f7f650c44324d25087a00484/docs/man/git-lfs-migrate.1.ronn).

See the [Git LFS 2.2.0 released](https://github.com/blog/2384-git-lfs-2-2-0-released)

> If you've tried to push a large file to GitHub without LFS, you might have seen the following error:

```
$ git push origin master
# ...
remote: error: gh001: large files detected. you may want to try git large file storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: see http://git.io/iept8g for more information.
remote: error: file a.psd is 1.2 gb; this exceeds github's file size limit of 100.00 mb
to github.com:ttaylorr/demo.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:ttaylorr/demo.git'
```

> You can use the **`git lfs migrate info`** command to see which files are causing the push failure:

```
$ git lfs migrate info
*.psd   1.2 GB   27/27 files(s)  100%
```

> Using the information above, you can determine which files to pluck out of your history and store in LFS:

```
$ git lfs migrate import --include="*.psd"
migrate: Sorting commits: ..., done
migrate: Rewriting commits: 100% (810/810), done
  master        f18bb746d44e8ea5065fc779bb1acdf3cdae7ed8 -> 35b0fe0a7bf3ae6952ec9584895a7fb6ebcd498b
migrate: Updating refs: ..., done

$ git push origin
Git LFS: (1 of 1 files) 1.2 GB / 1.2 GB
# ...
To github.com:ttaylorr/demo.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```